# Add Service Reference to WCF Service failed in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, https

I have simplest WCF service (visual studio template one), which is working fine with http but fails with https. below is little detail.

Here is how it looks like in IIS.

[image]

Here is web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>-->
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Here is browser when I ping it from ip

[image]

here is browser when I ping it from domain name.

[image]

All good at this point. however when I tried to add a service reference in visual studio, it failed with https but successful with http.

this is ip one (http)

[image]

this is domain name one (https)

[image]

detailed error message is

[image]

The question I have here is why visual studio's cant get hold of https://tar.tennis.com.au/testwcf/service1.svc and is ok with http://10.21.100.129/testwcf/service1.svc ?

surely one is http and other is https but then why browser had no issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

We need to add additional service endpoint for the support of https binding.
There are two ways to configure this, please refer to my example.
**1. simplified configuration**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**2. add the https service endpoint which uses the transport security.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services >
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="https"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="https">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.